# Navigate with payload was not handled by any navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I have a Stack Navigator:

```
    <NavigationContainer independent={true}>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={MainScreen}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Login"
          component={LoginScreen}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Register"
          component={RegisterScreen}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Savepost"
          component={SavePostScreen}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

and a BottomTab Navigator:

```
const MainScreen = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer independent={true}>
      <BottomTab.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          tabBarStyle: { backgroundColor: "black" },
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarActiveTintColor: "white",
          tabBarHideOnKeyboard: true
        }}
      >
        <BottomTab.Screen
          name="NewVideo"
          component={Newpost}
        />
      // Routes
      </BottomTab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

The question is that I want to navigate from the **newVideo** that is inside `BottomTab.Navigator` to the **savePost** inside the `Stack.Navigator`.
I tried this:
`navigation.navigate('Savepost', { source: result.assets })` and I get this problem?

Comment: Try adding the `BottomTab.Navigator` as a stack in the `Stack.Navigator`, then use the usually navigation function

Comment: Is it ok to do that? because I already added the `Stack.Navigator` as a bottomtab in `BottomTab.Navigator`.

Comment: You usually do it the other way, adding `BottomTab.Navigator` as a part of the `Stack.Navigator`. That way, all the stack available under the `Stack.Navigator` will be accessible to the child i.e `BottomTab.Navigator`